# Swagger API specs Request object design

Tags: rest, swagger, openapi

I have written an api specs following OpenAPI/Swagger Specification -

```
{
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "UserController"
        ],
        "operationId": "getUsers",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "accountID",
            "in": "path",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "number"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "sortKey",
            "in": "query",
            "required": false,
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "sortOrder",
            "in": "query",
            "required": false,
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "default response",
            "content": {
              "*/*": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/UserResponse"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

The API Request takes accountId, sortKey and sortOrder.  Should they should be wrapped in a Top level request object (getUsersRequest) ? What is the best practice?

```
{
  "GetUsersRequest": {
    "accountID": "String",
    "sortKey": "String",
    "sortOrder": "String"
  }
}
```

vs

```
{
  "accountID": "String",
  "sortKey": "String",
  "sortOrder": "String"
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "wrapped in a Top level request object (getUsersRequest)"?

Comment: So should there be a wrapper object getUsersRequest containing different params , or the parameters be passed directly?. Updated the question with details.

Answer (score 1):

Usually just use the properties. Using a "wrapper" object can be useful if the parameters belong to multiple **groups**.

For example if you have an api with paging:

```
/query?filter=findme&page=5&size=5
```

I see two **groups** of parameters.

1. the `filter` to limit the query result, that is the **main purpose** of the api.
2. the `page` & `size` parameters, which are more a technical help to limit the amount of results.

you can use an (wrapper) object to easily communicate that two of the three parameters belong together and are used for paging.

as yaml:

```
/query:
  get:
    description: ...
    parameters:
      - name: filter
        description: filters the data by the given value
        in: query
        schema:
          type: string
      - name: paging
        description: page selection
        in: query
        required: false
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Paging'

components:
  schemas:
    Paging:
      type: object
      properties:
        page:
          type: integer
        size:
          type: integer
```

So in your example you could group `sortKey` & `sortOrder` as a **view** group while `accountId` is the **main** parameter of the api.